# How to compare a combination of variables in a pythonic way

Tags: python, list

I'm migrating some text data from one DB to a new one, and I have to verify if the records are valid.

I have following variables: `first_name` and `complete_name`.

Since I have text data, I'm using some similarity function.  The conditions are:

```
def similar(first_name_1,first_name_2,complete_name_1,complete_name_2):
    temp_treshold  = 0

    temp_treshold = similarity_func(first_name_1,first_name_2)
    if  temp_treshold > threshold:
        return temp_treshold

    temp_treshold = similarity_func(first_name_1,complete_name_2)
    if  temp_treshold > threshold:
        return temp_treshold

    temp_treshold = similarity_func(complete_name_1,complete_name_2)
    if  temp_treshold > threshold:
        return temp_treshold

    temp_treshold = similarity_func(complete_name_1,complete_name_1)
    if  temp_treshold > threshold:
        return temp_treshold
```

How can I make this comparison in a cleaner way?

Comment: Are you *really* supposed to return integer values `0` and `1`?  This looks like a Boolean result.

Comment: Is there a reason you're returning 1 and 0 instead of True and False? Also, how is this ever going to return 0? I don't know what `similarity_func` is, but if it isn't `> threshold` when called on `complete_name_1` and itself, it's probably not a very useful similarity function.

Comment: @abarnert You are right, I'm actually returning the  threshold value.

Comment: @Prune I edited it.

Comment: I guess `similarity_func(complete_name_1,complete_name_1)` is always higher than `threshold`. So your function could just be `return 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your matches into a list of arguments to send to the routine.
Use the `any` function to check them all until a "good" one is found.

```
pairs = [
    (first_name_1,first_name_2),
    (first_name_1,complete_name_2),
    (complete_name_1,complete_name_2),
    (complete_name_1,complete_name_1)
]

return any(similarity_func(name1, name2) > threshold
               for name1, name2 in pairs)
```

This returns a Boolean.  If you truly want the integer, then cast the result to an `int` before returning.

---

**UPDATE AFTER OP CHANGE**

Okay; instead, you want to return the first similarity value that exceeds the threshold.  Updated code -- instead of the single-statement Boolean, use this:

```
for name1, name2 in pairs:
    sim = similarity_func(name1, name2)
    if sim > threshold:
       return sim
```

Answer (score 1):

With just four comparisons, and seemingly arbitrary ones, the way you've written (at least for the original version—see below for the edited version) is probably the clearest and most Pythonic solution. Explicit is good when it isn't violating DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

---

But if, say, you had a list of values and wanted to compare each against a list of other values, in some meaningful order, then it would definitely be worth abstracting things. For example:

```
lefts = [first_name_1, last_name_1, complete_name_1]
rights = [first_name_2, last_name_2, complete_name_2]
```

If you wanted to compare every `lefts` member with every `rights` member in the obvious order, copying and pasting 9 times and hoping you didn't get any of them wrong or out of order would be a bad idea. So you'd want to do something like this instead:

```
for left in lefts:
    for right in rights:
        if similarity_func(left, right) > threshold:
            return 1
return 0
```

Or, equivalently:

```
for left, right in itertools.product(lefts, rights):
    if similarity_func(left, right) > threshold:
         return 1
return 0
```

Or:

```
if any(similarity_func(left, right) > threshold
       for left, right in itertools.product(lefts, rights)):
    return 1
return 0
```

---

Since you've been changing your question… some of these have the nice advantage that you can easily change them to return something different. For example:

```
for left, right in itertools.product(lefts, rights):
    similarity = similarity_func(left, right)
    if similarity > threshold:
         return similarity
return 0
```

Your edit also means you *are* repeating quite a bit now, so, even if you do have a small and arbitrary set of comparisons in arbitrary order, I'd still abstract it. We can use `zip` over two ordered sequences (with repeats as needed) instead of `product`, and not much else has to change:

```
lefts = (first_name_1, first_name_1, complete_name_1, complete_name_1)
rights = (first_name_2, complete_name_2, complete_name_2, complete_name_1)
for left, right in zip(lefts, rights):
    similarity = similarity_func(left, right)
    if similarity > threshold:
         return similarity
return 0
```